sqlalchemy - dataclass with auto incrementing primary key
I'm using sqlalchemy to map database objects to Python dataclasses. I have a class with the primary key id.
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped, mapped_column, relationship, registry

__reg = registry()

@__reg.mapped_as_dataclass
class DeviceTest:
    __tablename__ = "device_test"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(server_default=seq.next_value(), primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    passed: bool = mapped_column()
    completed_at: datetime = mapped_column(insert_default=datetime.now(), default=None)


I want id to auto increment, so that I don't need to provide that to the constructor. How can I achieve this?
I can see in other answers that the Column object has an autoincrement parameter. This seems to work, but I'm not clear on what the difference between using Column and mapped_column is, and whether or not there will be issues going forward.
mapped_column also has an autoincrement parameter, but this does not remove id from the constructor.

Don't call it id if you can avoid it. id is the name of a Python builtin.

The solution was to set init=False
idx: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, init=False)


You can set the primary key attribute to false let unset the default value and you can set a primary key constraint to the field id.
I guess by doing this it would take the id and it will figure out how to auto increment it by itself.
I am also new feel free if i done any mistakes.
It does not work.
Working Solution is by @frimann Thanks.

Doesn't work - the __init__ still requires id as a positional argument
